# Session en PHP - Headers already sent in

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente error de "session_start(); Cannot start session when headers already sent in"

y me aparece el error en la parte derecha donde debería salir el nombre del usuario , lo raro es que cuando borro el `session_start();`, se quita el warning pero me sigue apareciendo como variable indefinida donde debería salir el nombre del usuario , otra cosa es que por este error no puedo añadir cosas al CRUD por que cuando añado actividad lo mando al usuario logeado.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['usuarios']['tipo'] != "User") {
        header('Location: ../Admin/admin.php'); 
    } else {
         header('Location: ../../index.php');
}
}

?>

<?php
  include ("conexion_bd.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>THANKS Digital</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
        user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0,
        minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Pr.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pagina-inicio4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/i.css" type="text/css">    
</head>

<!--Construcción del menú-->

<header>
    <div class="main-header-lider">

    <div class="main-header-home">  

        <span class="icon-ellipsis-v" id="btnmenu2" style="font-size:1.3em;">
        </span>
        <input class="input-header" readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuarios']['nombres']?>"> //aquí es donde imprimo el nombre del usario logeado
```

Comment: no hay un `session_start()` en el archivo que incluyes?

Answer (score 1):

Te falta controlar bien si las sesiones están iniciadas o no.

Es muy sencillo en realidad.
El error dice claramente, que no puede iniciar las sesiones una vez las ha iniciado.
Eso quiere decir, que no debemos iniciarlas, si ya han sido iniciadas cierto ??
Y como hacemos eso ?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

***Si la sesión NO está iniciada, iniciala.***

Con esto, en cada página que usa la sesión, deberías no obtener problemas.

---

BTW, no se por que, pero tienes el codigo PHP divido cuando no hay nada entre ellos.

cambia esto:

```
<?php
...
?>
<?php
...
?>
```

a solo uno completo

```
<?php
.
.
.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debe haber solo una llamada a `session_start();` en toda la petición. ¿Es posible que tengas otra en `conexion_bd.php` o en otro archivo incluido? Vamos a suponer que sí estás iniciando la sesión en otro archivo.

```
<?php
// Inicias la sesión y se envían encabezados al navegador
session_start();
?>

<?php
  // También tienes session_start() y no se pueden volver a enviar encabezados
  include ("conexion_bd.php");
?>
```

Primero, ten en cuenta que no debes haber enviado **absolutamente nada** al navegador, ni siquiera espacios o saltos de línea y voy a poner algunos ejemplos usando `|` como indicador de inicio de línea.

Error por salto de línea antes de iniciar código PHP

```
|
|<?php
|   session_start();
```

Error por espacios o tabuladores antes de iniciar código PHP

```
|  <?php
|  session_start();
```

Error por enviar HTML previo

```
|<html><head>
|<?php
|session_start();
```

Error por enviar contenido previo

```
|<?php
|    echo 'Hola, mundo';
|    session_start();
```

Si ninguno de estos es tu caso, entonces sí estás tratando de iniciar sesión dos o más veces. Una solución (la  mejor) es incluir primero el script que inicia sesión:

```
<?php
include 'conexion_bd.php';
// Comenzar a usar las variables de sesión
if(isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    // Aquí lo que tengas que hacer con la sesión
}
```

Algo mucho menos recomendable es que cada que quieras iniciar sesión revises si no se ha iniciado todavía con [session_status()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.php)

```
<?php
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    // Todavía no se ha iniciado la sesión
    session_start();
}
```

Luego, en el `if` revisas si existe la variable de sesión usuarios y rediriges a otra página, por lo que solo podrás ingresar a la actual cuando no existe esa variable y, por supuesto, aparece como indefinida cuando intentas usarla:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    if($_SESSION['usuarios']['tipo'] != "User") {
        header('Location: ../Admin/admin.php'); 
    } else {
         // Hay sesión iniciada, pero rediriges
         header('Location: ../../index.php');
    }
}
// Aquí $_SESSION['usuarios'] no está definida
```

Lo más lógico sería verificar que no existe la sesión para redirigir a `index.php` y después analizar el tipo para redirigir a `admin.php`.

**Muy importante:** la función `header()` solo envía un encabezado al navegador, pero el script continúa su ejecución, por lo que debes terminar con [exit](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exit) o `die`, que son equivalentes.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    // La sesión no existe, redirigir a index.php
    header('Location: ../../index.php');
    // Finalizar ejecución del script
    exit;
}
// ¿No es el tipo de usuario correcto?
if($_SESSION['usuarios']['tipo'] != "User") {
    // Redirigir y finalizar ejecución
    header('Location: ../Admin/admin.php');
    exit;
}
// Ahora sí está definida $_SESSION['usuarios']
```

Answer (score 1):

***Cannot start session when headers already sent in***

Ahí te está indicando que no se puede hacer session_start porque ya se han enviado las cabeceras. Las cabeceras normalmente se mandan en cuanto algo de contenido es escrito ( cuando se hace un echo, print_r, se imprime un error por pantalla, etc).

Tu problema está en que en algún lugar de tu código, antes de llegar al session_start(), se ha escrito algo de contenido ( por lo cual ya se han enviado las cabeceras ) y al ser session_start() una función que envia y depende de varias cabeceras, te da error y te indica que ***No se puede empezar una sesión cuando las cabeceras ya han sido enviadas***

Tienes que buscar en tu código que es lo que produce algo de texto en pantalla antes de llegar al session_start() y una de dos, evitar que se imprima ese texto o mover el session_start() para situarlo antes de donde se imprime el texto.

Ten en cuenta que los espacios en blanco, carácteres especiales, etc también podrían llegar a contar para enviar las cabeceras según donde estén puestos.
Incluso, algunos editores de windows, insertan un caracter ( llamado caracter BOM ) que es "invisible" y sirve para indicar que la codificación del texto es UTF-8, UTF-16 o UTF-32 ( puedes leer más aquí https://cybmeta.com/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent )