# ¿Establecer la una conexión a la BD para generar un Excel con PHP?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, conexión

Quiero generar un archivo Excel con ayuda de PhpSpreadsheet, resulta ser que mi código localmente funciona perfecto, sin errores al generar dicho archivo.
Pero cuando lo subo al servidor, en pantalla me muestra símbolos al querer exportar el excel,
estaba haciendo varias pruebas y encontré que si establezco la conexión de la bd desde el mismo archivo donde genero el excel, me lo genera sin problema.

Que podría ser que estuviera pasando?

Este es mi codigo para generar mi archivo:

```
<?php

// Declaramos la librería
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
// BD
require "../conexion/dbconect.php";



use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;



$sql = "SELECT * FROM usu";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$write_array = array();
$fileName = "excel.xlsx";
$write_array[] = array("id","ade","ad");
if($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $write_array[] = array($row["id"],$row["ade"],$row["ad"]);
    }
}
$con->close();
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($write_array,NULL,'A1');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("My Excel");

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
ob_end_clean();
$writer->save('php://output');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de dbconect:

```
<?php
function connect(){
    return new mysqli("localhost","root","","bd");
}
$con = connect();
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {//asignamos la codificación comprobando que no falle
       die("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8");
} 
?>
```

Comment: y cual es el error???

Comment: Una disculpa, actualice mi pregunta con el error

Comment: es Xlsx o xlsx???

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `dbconect.php`, es probable que tengas una salida (echo, print_r, var_dump, etc) y eso hace que no se pueda descargar el archivo.

Comment: @Triby Ya edite mi pregunta y puse el código de dbconect.php

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent afecta las mayusculas?

Comment: @Triby tal vez no tiene el error el archivo dbconect.php puesto que si ese mismo codigo lo pongo directamente desde el archivo donde genero el excel, funciona bien

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/455797/54039), un espacio o salto de línea antes de enviar el contenido puede ser el causante del error. En `dbconect.php` elimina el `?>` del final, probablemente tengas espacios o saltos de línea posteriores y asegúrate que la codificación es UTF8 **sin BOM**.

Comment: No es conveniente tener [preguntas duplicadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501029/problemas-al-exportar-excel-con-phpspreadsheet) y creo que tener dos o más usuarios también puede traerte problemas.