# Hacer login en un hosting

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

Estoy intentando implementar un pequeño sistema en php y mysql en un hosting para que funcione en línea, este es el código de un archivo login.php que procesa los datos que se ingresan desde el formulario, el problema, funciona perfectamente en local pero en el servidor no funciona, no me da ningún error solo una pagina en blanco. Alguien sabría decirme el motivo? o si existe algún otro método? Me interesa usar principalmente las variables de sesión

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";
require 'funciones.php';
require 'sesion.php';
    
    $usu = isset($_POST["usu"])?$_POST["usu"]:"";
    $pass = isset($_POST["pass"])?$_POST["pass"]:"";
    
    if(empty($usu) || empty($pass)){
      msg_sesion("Todos los campos son necesarios");
        llevame_a("../index.php");
    }
    
   $sql=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM user_local WHERE user ='$usu'");

   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1){
        $res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

        //if($res["pass"]==$pass){
        if(password_verify($pass, $res["pass"])){
          $_SESSION["usu"]=$usu;
          $_SESSION["nombre"] = $res["nombre"];
          $_SESSION["id"] = $res["id_usu"];
          $_SESSION["permiso"] = $res["permiso"];
          $_SESSION["mesa"] = $res["mesa"];
          $_SESSION["orden"] = $res["orden"];
          $_SESSION["local"] = $res["local"];
            
            msg_sesion("Ha iniciado sesion");
            llevame_a("../pages/inicio.php");
            
        }else{
            msg_sesion("Contraseña incorrecta");
            llevame_a("../index.php");
        }
        
   }else{
       msg_sesion("Nombre de usuario inexistente");
       llevame_a("../index.php");
   }
?>
```

Actualización: en el servidor encontre un archivo de error_log con este mensaje;
session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/eleczgco/public_html/login/sesion.php on line 2

este es mi archivo sesion.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function msg_sesion($msg=""){

        if(empty($msg)){
            if(isset($_SESSION["msg"])){
                $msg=$_SESSION["msg"];
                $_SESSION["msg"]="";
                return $msg;

            }else{

                return "";
                
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION["msg"]=$msg;
            
        }
        
    }
    

    function verifico(){
        if(!estas_logeado()){
                msg_sesion("Debes iniciar sesión para ingresar");
                header("Location:../index.php");
                exit();
        }
    }
    
    function estas_logeado(){
        return isset($_SESSION["id"]);
    }

?>
```

Lo de la sesión lo arregle colocando un arroba al sesion_star, @session_start(); con eso dejo de aparecerme ese error en el log, pero ahora surge uno nuevo; Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/eleczgco/public_html/login/login.php:1) in /home/eleczgco/public_html/login/funciones.php on line 3

el archivo funciones.php solo tiene esto

```
<?php   
    function llevame_a($url){
        header("Location:".$url);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Cambiaste la configuración de tu conexión por los parámetros del servidor, que a veces se nos olvida y dejamos el de *Localhost*. Otra cosa, a veces inspeccionar el documento HTML podrás ver algún error que no se ve en pantalla.

Comment: En mi experiencia utilizando un servidor, en ese tenía que realizar la base de datos desde el cpanel, recordar un usuario y contraseña que no pueden ser los mismos que usarías en las pruebas en localhost, a menos que quieras que sean esas las credenciales, y como bien menciona DBE, la configuración de tu conexión, revísala y comenta si era eso.

Comment: La conexión esta bien, tiene todos los datos correctos, el error que encuentro es en un archivo de sesión

Comment: Hay servidores que requieren el fichero de php codificado en ANSI en vez de en UTF8. Prueba cambiando la codificación de caracteres a ver qué tal...

Comment: Poner `@` no es una solución, solo oculta los posibles mensajes de error y va a complicar mucho el mantenimiento de tu proyecto por no saber exactamente lo que está pasando. Debes tener `session_start();` antes de cualquier salida (HTML, espacios, saltos de línea, texto, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el archivo funciones.php no tenia una etiqueta de cierre

```
<?php   
    function llevame_a($url){
        header("Location:".$url);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Solo me falto esto

> ?>

al final del documento

Comment: Creo que ahí podría estar mas entendible

Comment: Es lo que yo creía, pero el error se soluciono al colocar eso, busque sobre ese error y lo único que encontré útil fue mencionaban que no debía existir espacios en blanco después de la etiqueta de apertura y cierre, ahí me di cuenta que no tenia una etiqueta de cierre, lo coloque y funciono.

Comment: Dudo que esa haya sido la solución, de hecho, en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) se recomienda no incluir etiqueta de cierre `?>`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/455797/54039) para ver si te queda más claro el origen de esos mensajes.

Comment: El error que apareció al principio sobre sesion_star(); se soluciono simplemente al agregarle un arroba al inicio @session_start();... la solución que plantee al final se refiere a un error en la modificación de la cabecera en php al intentar hacer header location

Comment: Anteponer `@` NO soluciona errores, solo los ignora y el comportamiento del script puede resultar muy diferente a lo que esperas. Lee la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).