# session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Esto me da este error: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent.

Estoy tratando de hacer un login, tengo todo sobre la conexión bien pero no entiendo bien estos problemas porque se pueden causar, pero me salen estos errores que no entiendo la razón de ellos, cuando quito la parte de session_start():, agradecería que alguien me ayudara con este problema.

ingreso.php (Codigo del login) es donde tengo el inicio de sesión conectandolo con ingreso.php (Código del formulario) que este seria de la pagina de ingreso.

Este es mi código:

````
//Conex.php
<?php 
// Defino las constantes de conexion=+
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$basedatos="programming_for_all"; //Aqui coloco el nombre de la base de datos de mi proyecto
$pass="";
$msj="No se ha encontrado enlace con el servidor o la base de datos";

//Constructor de conexion, utilizamos el mètodo mysqli() para realizar la conexiòn 
$conexion= new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$basedatos) or die ($msj);

$acento= $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//Si no se puede conectar, envìa un mensaje de error 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
}
 ?>


//ingreso.php (Codigo del login)
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
if (strlen($_POST['name']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['lastname']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['password']) >= 1) {
$NAME = $_POST['name'];
$LASTNAME = $_POST['lastname'];
$EMAIL = $_POST['email'];
$PASSWORD = $_POST['password'];
session_start();
include("../Modelo/conex.php");
$_SESSION['name']=$NAME;   

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nombre_us='$NAME' & Apellido_us='$LASTNAME' & Correo_us='$EMAIL' & Clave_us='$PASSWORD'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($filas){
    
    ?>
    <h3 class="ok">¡Te has inscrito correctamente!</h3>
    <?php

} else {
    ?>
    <h1>ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACIÓN</h1>
    <?php
}


mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
}
}

//ingreso.php (Codigo del formulario)
<div class="box-ingreso">
<div class="ingreso-box">
    <img class="logo" src="../vista/assets/media/img/Website logone.jfif" alt="Logo de progamacion">
    <h1>Ingresa aquí</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <!--Usuario-->
        <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input class="Nombre"  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
        <!---->
        <!--Usuario-->
        <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input class="Apellido"  name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido">
        <!---->
        <!--Correo-->
        <label for="Correo">Correo</label>
        <input class="Correo"  name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico">
        <!---->   
        <!--Contraseña-->
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input class="contraseña" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
        <!---->
       <center><button type="Submit" class="submit" name="login">Ingresar</button></center> 
                
        <a href="">¿Ha olvidado su contraseña?</a><br>
        <a href="../vista/registro.php">Registrarse</a>
    </form>
    <?php
      include('../vista/assets/datos/ingreso.php');
    ?>
</div>
</div>```
````

Comment: Prueba a colocar esto: `include("../Modelo/conex.php");` después de `session_start();`

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: ¿Eso es todo lo que tienes en `ingreso.php`? El problema que estás teniendo es porque en alguna parte hay una salida por pantalla antes de `session_start()`

Comment: Si ahí esta todo el código, por eso no entiendo que es lo que sucede

Comment: Es que no puedes poner en un mismo archivo el formulario y el inicio de sesión. Debes trasladar ese código a un archivo `.php` aparte, y poner ese archivo en el parámetro `action` del formulario. Otra cosa que puedes hacer (menos elegante) es sacar el `session_start()` del `if` y ponerlo en la primera línea del script.

Comment: Si yo lo tengo asi, por eso puse **ingreso.php (Codigo del login) y ingreso.php (Codigo del formulario)** porque los dos archivos se llaman de la misma manera pero estan en diferentes carpetas

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/455797/54039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes imprimprimir caracteres antes de enviar las cabeceras.
dicho esto :

El inicio del documento deber ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Inmediatamente después de la etiqueta de apertura `<?php`

Esto da error

```
echo texto;
<?php 
session_start();
```

Esto da error

```html
<?php

session_start();
```

Esto da error

```html
<?php 
include "algundocumento.php"
session_start();
```

Esto da error

```html
 <?php 
 //algun comentario antes o un simple caracter como un tab o un espacio
 session_start();
```